# How to integrate search engine of a wiki with a search engine of a QA system?

Tags: google-app-engine, search-engine, wiki, question2answer

In a knowledge management project I need to use a wiki engine ( I'm thinking about DokuWiki ) and a Question and Answer system ( I'm  thinking about Question2Answer), and I need to create a Search Funcionality that search in both systems (Wiki and QA) and return what has been found.  ( Like a Google of the two systems in same time)

Anyone knows a direction to help me  how to do it properly?

Comment: you probably want to do this on GCE not appengine. note s.o. is not about recommending a tool or library.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what is GCE?

Comment: www.google.com first result

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the wiki side, but you can write your own search plugin for Question2Answer that let you integrate your own search results into those of Q2A. [See the docs](http://question2answer.org/modules.php?module=search) for more info.

If your wiki software has an API or functions you can call to find search results, then in Q2A you can use the `process_search` method in your plugin, call your wiki search function and add the results to the Q2A results.

---

Having said all that, you might find it easier to integrate [Google Custom Search Engine](https://cse.google.com/cse/) into your site!